# Route not displaying the correct page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got 2 sections to my site, the admin side and the public side. The issue I'm having is that if I go to for example `admin/menus` then I go to my public side instead of going to the menus page.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried to re-arrange the order of the routes in my public side but that didn't work and I've drawn a blank as to what I've done wrong.

My public routes

```
<?php

    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'OpenController@index',
        'as' => 'index',
    ]);

    Route::get('/{id}', 'OpenController@content');

    Route::post('/contact', [
        'uses' => 'OpenController@contact',
        'as' => 'contact',
    ]);

    Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', [
        'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
        'as' => 'product.item',
    ]);

    Route::any('/search', [
        'uses' => 'OpenController@search',
        'as' => 'search'
    ]);
```

my admin menus route

```
Route::resource('admin/menus', 'MenusController');
```

My productItem function

```
public function productItem($category, $slug)
{

    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();

    $contact = Contact::all();

    $single_product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->get();

    return view('open::public.single_item', compact('menus_child', 'contact', 'single_product'));
}
```

The error come in with this route

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
    'as' => 'product.item',
]);
```

If I remove this route then it works, but I need this route so I can't remove it.

If I'm missing something else that I need to give please let me know.

Comment: what's the error, can you go into more detail please?

Comment: Make sure you add your admin route `admin/menus` before following route `/{category}/{slug}`

Comment: Your route `/admin/menus` matches the route `/{category}/{slug}`. The order of your defined routes matters, so explicit routes like `/admin/menus` should  be defined **before** wildcard routes such as `/{category}/{slug}`, otherwise you'll run into this issue often.

Comment: @TimLewis - I'm using caffeinated module so that I have my stuff all modular, so how would I specify the `admin/menus` to be on top.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that module so I can't really make a recommendation on your approach.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if u put it at the top, but it may clash with other routes i think.

`Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
    'as' => 'product.item',
]);`

you can try like this if u want

`Route::get('/category/{category}/{slug}', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    echo "ok";
});`

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix the route `/{category}/{slug}` to avoid conflicts. So replace:

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
    'as' => 'product.item',
]);
```

By:

```
Route::get('/open/{category}/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
    'as' => 'product.item',
]);
```

And update your links to that route in your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
    'as' => 'product.item',
]);
```

Will catch every combination of path that have two items `/admin/menus`, `/admin/anything` or `/foo/bar`. You are probably going to run into the same problem with

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'OpenController@content');
```

If you can not rename your routes, you need to put all the more restrictive routes on top and your less restrictive routes on the bottom.

```
Route::resource('admin/menus', 'MenusController');


Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@index',
    'as' => 'index',
]);

Route::post('/contact', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@contact',
    'as' => 'contact',
]);

Route::any('/search', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@search',
    'as' => 'search'
]);

Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@productItem',
    'as' => 'product.item',
]);

Route::get('/{id}', 'OpenController@content');
```

**UPDATE**

You have a few options.

Here are two of them.

You can limit what the route will accept with RegEx.

See [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters) > Regular Expression Constraints

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', function () {
    return 'hello';
})->where('category', '[one]*[two]*[three]*[four]*[five]*');
```

Or you can change the [caffeine route through its config](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine#configuration).

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=genealabs-laravel-caffeine
```

Then change the `route` in `/app/config/genealabs-laravel-caffeine.php`

There are some other ways as well. I'd just up a quick test site and start messing with routes to see what works the best for your needs.

Comment: I'm using caffeinated module so that I have my stuff all modular, so how would I specify the admin/menus to be on top